# Using jquery with ajax and json in MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an MVC application (using MVC 4 beta).

I want my site to be responsive similar to google apps which immediately show data with no page refresh showing and quick.

I am looking for a good example where data is saved to the database using ajax calls from the jquery and sending data using json.

any example relevant would be great to get my head around it

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are dozens of examples for this canonical scenario.

Just an example of two to begin with:

1. http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views
2. http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: cheers for the reply. Looking at stackoverflow when you click on a menu item such as tags how is it so quick in bringing data through?

Comment: Their servers are quick, the roundtrip is quick. You can check it in Chrome Dev Tools / FireBug / IE Developer tools / Fiddler.